# No alarm sound after update from CM 11 to CM 13

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, 6.0-marshmallow, audio, alarm

I recently updated my Samsung Galaxy S3 from Cyanogenmod 11.x to the latest 13.0. Despite some transitional issues, everything seemed fine.

Except that I almost overslept because the alarm was silent; only the vibration went off.

I have been through *all* the settings and combinations of modes (airplane mode, system profile, ...) -- volume is turned up everywhere but alarms are always silent. What do I have to do?

I use the system clock/alarm app.

Comment: I'm posting this self-answered question in the spirit of [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) since I was not able to find a solution on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the update skrewed up the link between alarms and ringtones resp. alarm sound. For me, the alarm app showed `17` instead of a sound name.

You simply have to choose a new sound (or reselect the old one, as it where) and you have audible alarms back.